# ANOVA post hoc with concerned about the sphericity

Tags: r, anova, t-test, post-hoc, sphericity

According to [this post](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/) the best way to do post hoc analysis in ANOVA in R is t-test + ptukey. Because lme + glht "essentially assumes the sphericity assumption holds".

How are t-test + ptukey "concerned about the sphericity"? What are the disadvantages of this method?